Multiprocessing shared memory to pass large arrays between processes
Context: I need to analyse some weather data for every hour of the year. For each hour, I need to read in some inputs for each hour before performing some calculation. One of these inputs is a very large numpy array x , which does not change and is the same for every hour of the year. The output is then a vector (1D numpy array) y, which contains the calculation result for every hour of the year.
Objective: Speed up the calculation time using multiprocessing module. In particular, I am trying to pass x to each process using the shared_memory submodule of multiprocessing.
I'm running CPython 3.10.8 on Windows 10, with Spyder 5.3.3 as the IDE.
Code (simplified for testing purposes):
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

def multiprocessing_function(args):
    nn, shm_name, y_shm_name, shape, dtype, N = args
    existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)
    x = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=dtype, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
    existing_y_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=y_shm_name)
    y = np.ndarray((N,), dtype=dtype, buffer=existing_y_shm.buf)
    y[nn] = 1
    existing_shm.close()
    existing_y_shm.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.rand(int(1e7), 16)
    N = 8760 # Number of hours in a year
            
    dtype = x.dtype
    shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=x.nbytes)
    shm_array = np.ndarray(x.shape, dtype=x.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)
    np.copyto(shm_array, x)
    y_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=N * x.itemsize)
    y_array = np.ndarray((N,), dtype=x.dtype, buffer=y_shm.buf)
    
    args_case = [(nn, shm.name, y_shm.name, x.shape, dtype, N) for nn in range(N)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(multiprocessing_function, args_case)
    
    y = np.array(y_array)

    shm.close()
    y_shm.close()
    shm.unlink()
    y_shm.unlink()

Issue: When I run the code, it returns the correct vector, but 50% of the time, I get a "Windows fatal exception: access violation" and the kernel crashes. If I then change the size of the array, it might have no issues, but if I restart Spyder and try to rerun the same code with the new array size, the same error would come up and the kernel would crash again. This inconsistent behavior is incredibly strange. I have a feeling this is a memory leakage issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Objective: Speed up ? Stop using Spyder, stop using "expensive" setup with zero added value. Refactor code to become mutually independent ( having no communications between processes, zero-sharing means zero-locking ) and turn to use high performance tricks, may use O/S well cached .memmap()-s to reduce RAM footprints of many-(full Python interpreter RAM copies in Windows)-processes, to prevent crashes.

I could not reproduce this on my PC (Python 3.10.8, Windows 10, PowerShell). Successful 10 times out of 10. Can you reproduce this without Spyder?

Nice to know, @ken yet with all due respect, your ( no matter how big ) RAM space will most probably not match the O/P's and the good news on your side does not help to solve the issues that remains the same - how to navigate O/P to fix the problem on machine, that was used and where the crashes remain to re-appear.

You could try to use a memory manager instead of a shared memory. I'm not 100% sure how thread-safety is accomplished with a shared memory object. But it is when using a memory manager. Then you can at least rule out this issue.

I'm new to parallel processing so I have no idea how to investigate it. I haven't tried doing it outside of Spyder, I might give it a go tomorrow. However, I managed to use multiprocessing rawarray to do what I wanted. Might not be optimal, but the workaround is fine for my needs so I'll just settle for that. Thanks for the comments!

Either Spyder itself or the IPython shell is trying to access one of your shared numpy arrays after the shared memory file has been closed. My first guess is that Spyder is trying to populate it's "Variable Explorer" pane by enumerating local variables. This causes an access to the numpy array, but the memory location it is pointing to is no longer valid because the SharedMemory has been closed.
SharedMemory creates files on the filesystem (so they're sharable) in a way that they will only reside in memory (so they're fast). Then you are given memory-mapped access to that file as a buffer. There are some differences depending on the OS, but in general this holds true. Like any other file, you have a bit more responsibility to clean up after yourself: close() and unlink().
Unfortunately Numpy has no way to know the buffer it's pointing to has been closed, so it will go ahead and try to access the same memory it was previously pointing to. Windows calls it "Access Violation", and everyone else calls it "Segmentation Fault".
To solve this problem:

You can simply change the settings in Spyder to run scripts in an external terminal and not access the arrays after the shm's are closed.
You can call del shm_array and del y_array after you're done with them (right before closing the shm's). This will remove them from the module scope so the IPython kernel doesn't try to access them.
You can put the stuff in a function so your numpy arrays go out of scope and get garbage collected automatically when the function returns.
You can just not close the shm files: Like other file handles, they get closed as part of the python process exiting. Closing your current shell (and starting a new one) should do the trick. On windows if no process has a handle to any given SHM open, it will automatically be deleted. On Linux (and maybe MacOS?) the file will only be deleted when calling unlink or when the computer is rebooted.


This worked like a charm! I tested your 2nd and 4th suggestions and there haven't been any issues so far. Thank you!
